# Comment utiliser « il y a » ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, locutions

J'ai cherché la traduction de l'expression « il y a » mais je suis confus. Le livre que j'utilise déclare que l'expression « il y a » signifie « there are / there is » en anglais. Cependant, l'auteur mentionne qu'il y a beaucoup d'emplois de cette expression, comme par exemple « Il n'y a qu'à leur dire », qui signifie « Just tell them » en anglais. Donc, j'aimerais savoir dans quelles situations on doit utiliser l'expression « il y a » ?

Comment: @comet hapax d'ajax Thank you for editing my question.

Answer (score 7):

"Il y a" est une expression toute faite non porteuse de sens, un peu comme "there is". Elle peut être utilisée dans de nombreux contextes:

- Pour exprimer la présence. En général "there is" est alors une bonne traduction:

  > Il y a trois pommes dans mon panier. → There are three apples in my basket.
- Cela peut aussi servir à insister sur la présence de quelque chose à ne pas oublier de prendre en compte, souvent une obligation. Cette application est en général plus familière ou ironique:

  > N'oubliez pas qu'il y a encore deux tartes à manger ! → Don't forget you still have to eat two more pies!
  >
  > Pour ceux qui s'ennuient, il y a de la vaisselle à faire. → For those who are bored, you can do the dishes.
- La négative de ce dernier usage est aussi très employée, notamment pour exprimer la non-nécessité:

  > Il n'y a pas de souci à se faire. → There is no need to worry.
  >
  > Il n'y a qu'à décaler la réunion à la semaine prochaine → Just move the meeting to next week.
  >
  > Il n'y a pas à épiloguer, ma décision est prise. → No more blather, I made my decision.
- Il peut aussi s'agir d'une localisation temporelle:

  > Il y a deux ans, j'ai fait une terrible erreur → Two years ago, I did a terrible mistake.
  >
  > Il y a peu, je l'ai revu → Lately, I saw him again.

Answer (score 1):

**Il y a = There is / There are.** *en général*

Cas particuliers:

Il n'y a **qu**'à + infinitif = Il suffit de + infinitif.

Il y a + *durée* =  indication temporelle dans le passé.

Comment: Alors, Il n'y a qu'à porter= Il suffit de porter, qui signifie « Just wear » en anglais.